# Reflection - getting private field value

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I am testing viewmodel and would like to access private field:

```
    val currentTrainingField = viewModel.javaClass.getDeclaredField("currentTraining")
    currentTrainingField.isAccessible = true
    val currentTraining = currentTrainingField.get(currentSetField)
```

I receive an error:
Can not set com.myapp.Training field com.myapp.WorkoutExerciseViewModel.currentTraining to java.lang.reflect.Field

How should I handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```kotlin
val currentTrainingField = viewModel.javaClass.getDeclaredField("currentTraining")
currentTrainingField.isAccessible = true


val currentTraining = currentTrainingField.get(viewModel)
```

You relaxed the field's scope but you should access the value of that field on a specfic object, here `viewModel`.